# Auto-syncing two SQL Servers in ASP.NET/C# client/server apps

Tags: c#, sql-server, synchronization

I have the following architecture: local C# desktop app with SQL Server Express and a central web app with SQL Server Enterprise, with db per local app.

I need to sync those two databases semi-automatically, but with some controls (and info) from an local desktop and web apps.

For example, I want for user to see when sync start, when it ended, etc. Also, if synced ok or there was an error.

What is the best solution for this problem ?

I see that there are two technologies: merge replication (works only on SQL Server level with no app interference), and discontinued Sync framework, with lots of problems. Should I create my app module for this?

Update: just to note, a web app will be fine without this, however, the reason for this sync is that as I need to have offline functionality, i.e., when network is offline app must work regulary.

Comment: Why are you not simply using the network SQL server for everything? Are you trying to write an "offline" functionality?

Comment: Why not use transactional replication? That way the two databases are kept in sync through the native SQL Server mechanism.

Comment: Does your network have a time server?

Comment: @oadflakz yes, when offline it must work.

Comment: @jdweng no, we don't have it.

Comment: @Kevin does this work other way around? I.e., sometimes I need to add something on my main SQL Server and this too need to be replicated to local app.

Comment: In transactional replication the publisher db pushes changes out to the subscriber db. If you need to go both directions, log shipping would probably work better. Keep in mind though, log shipping is not near real time, it has to be performed and only sends the delta transactions and I'm not entirely sure you can do it programmatically.

Comment: @Keven In MSDN for transaction repl, it says "The Publisher or Subscriber is a non-SQL Server database, such as Oracle.". In my case both are SQL servers.

Comment: You can make any server a time server to get the databases synchronized.

Comment: To answer myself, SQL Server merge replication is the best way to do it.